# Есть ДЗ. Не могу сообразить как дальше сделать, смог только первые 2 пункта

Tags: javascript

```
// 
   1. Получить данные всех пользователей из https://reqres.in/api/users

   2. Вывести в консоль фамилии всех пользователей в цикле
   3. Вывести все данные всех пользователей, фамилия которых начинается на F

   4. Вывести следующее предложение: Наша база содержит данные следующих пользователей:  и 
      далее в этой же строке через запятую имена и фамилии всех пользователей. Использовать 
      метод reduce

   5. Вывести названия всех ключей в объекте пользователя.


      Требования

      Данные можно получить один раз
      Пункты 2-5 можно сделать в одном месте, но вывод разделить следующим кодом:

      console.log('-----------');
      console.log('Пункт №1:')
      console.log('-----------');
      // код для выполнения пункта 1
      console.log('-----------');
      console.log('Пункт №2:')
      console.log('-----------');
      // код для выполнения пункта 2


 // все что смог сделать

'use strict'

fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=12')
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
}).then((body) => {
    console.log(body);
    body.data.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.last_name)
       
    });        
});
```

Comment: Не видно попыток реализации других заданий.

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так думаю

```js
fetch('https://reqres.in/api/users?per_page=12')
.then((response) => {
    console.log(response);
    return response.json();
}).then((body) => {
    
    console.log('-----------');
    console.log('Пункт №1:')
    console.log('-----------');
    console.log(body);
    
    console.log('-----------');
    console.log('Пункт №2:')
    console.log('-----------');
    body.data.forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.last_name)
    });
 
    console.log('-----------');
    console.log('Пункт №3:')
    console.log('-----------');
    body.data.filter(item=>item.last_name.startsWith('F')).forEach(element => {
        console.log(element.last_name)
    });

    console.log('-----------');
    console.log('Пункт №4:')
    console.log('-----------');
    console.log(body.data.reduce((acc, item)=>acc + item.first_name + " " + item.last_name +', ', "Наша база содержит данные следующих пользователей:"));
    
    console.log('-----------');
    console.log('Пункт №5:')
    console.log('-----------');
    Object.keys(body).forEach(element=>
        console.log(element)
    );

           
});
```

Comment: Подскажите, почему после 2 then, мы просто реализуем дальше алгоритм, а не снова пишем then и далее перебираем через forEach,чтобы найти фамилии которые начинаются на F

Comment: я добавлял 3й then, но выдавало ошибку

Comment: Потому что так по спецификации результат обрабатывается в 2 шага

Comment: Спасибо
пробую не через startsWith

Comment: body.data.filter(item => item.last_name).forEach(element => {
                if (item.last_name[0] === 'F') {
                    console.log(element.last_name)
                }
            })

Comment: что не так, почему не работает?

Comment: Вопросов много толку мало. element и item ничего то разные переменные?